# Disable "Documentation Comments" warning for selected files

Tags: xcode, documentation, warnings

Xcode has the ability to check for Documentation Comments issues and report warnings when something is not quite right. For instance, I've added Facebook SDK to my project using CocoaPods. At some point in the file `FBError.h` there's the following code:

```
/*!
 @typedef NS_ENUM (NSInteger, FBErrorCategory)

 @abstract Indicates the Facebook SDK classification for the error

 @discussion
 */
```

Note that the `@discussion` parameter is empty, and Xcode will generate a warning accordingly:

> Empty paragraph passed to '@discussion' command

However, Facebook SDK is not the only library I've added to my project, and the Issues tab is full of other documentation related warnings from 3rd party files, from the Pods I installed.

I'd like to know how to suppress this kind of warning for those files.

Comment: Depending on how you have your project setup and which Project(s), Target(s), and Dependencies have the Documentation Comments (CLANG_WARN_DOCUMENTATION_COMMENTS) set to Yes will determine which avenues are open for suppressing things.  Could you post a sanitized version of your podspec and list project-level and/or target-level(s) where you've set 'Documentation Comments' to YES?

Comment: Try this with XCode 8
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42991455/silencing-documentation-issue-warnings-in-xcode/43234526#43234526](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42991455/silencing-documentation-issue-warnings-in-xcode/43234526#43234526)

Answer (score 41):

You can use this snippet to suppress the warnings:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdocumentation"

#import <YourHeader.h>

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

see this cocoapod-issue for details: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1481 (snippet comes from there)

Comment: Thanks!  It's not great having to do this wherever the headers are imported, but it's better than disabling the warnings for the entire target.

Comment: it's less typing if you create a macro for the pragma settings, i.e.: #define DISABLE_DWARN \
_Pragma("clang diagnostic push") \
_Pragma("clang diagnostic warning \"-Wdeprecated-declarations\"") but I don't think you can use #import in a macro.

Comment: I get a warning unless the last line is `#pragma clang diagnostic pop`

Comment: This is fantastic. I've been working with the aws-sdk-cpp library in Xcode, and it generates hundreds of "Documentation Issue" warnings. These pragmas solve that problem.

Answer (score 18):

I face the same issue when using cocoapods.
If you are using cocoapods, and wants to silence the warnings from pods files,you can do this:

1. In your target's `Build Settings`, select `All` && `Levels`, then search for `documentation comments`.
2. Then change your Project's `documentation comments` to `NO`,change  your target's `documentation comments` to `YES`.
3. Then Clean build floder(Press Command+Option+Shift+K), rebuid your target.You will silence the `Document issue` warning from your pods files, and still have them for your own files.
4. In case you want to silence your own files as well, keep your target's `documentation comments` to `NO` will do the trick.
5. The result will look like this:

[image]

Comment: documentation warnings still appear after following the steps in your question, even after clean rebuilt

Comment: @Raptor check both targets and project `Documentation Comments`, select 'Levels' at the top left corner, to see what the `Resolved` result is, and what override it .

Comment: I had to turn documentation comments off when selecting my Pods sub project to get the warnings to disappear.

Answer (score 8):

What about ignoring warning coming from library added by cocoapods?

In your podfile, add

```
inhibit_all_warnings!
```

to remove all warning

Or

```
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', :inhibit_warnings => true
```

to remove warnings from specific library.

Comment: Thank you. This works for me.`# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.3'
inhibit_all_warnings!
pod 'RealmSwift'`