# Silencing "Documentation issue" warnings in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, documentation, warnings

E.g.
`'@param' command used in a comment that is not attached to a function declaration`

This warning is valid, however, I am compiling 3rd party code and wish to not have to alter the original source.

I am running Xcode 8.2.1.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I was able to suppress these warnings by going to

**Project -> Build Settings -> Apple LLVM 8.1 - Warnings - All Languages,** and switching the "Documentation Comments" to **No**.

(To find the setting, I typed "Documentation" into the search box under Build Settings.)

Comment: This doesn't silence third party documentation in imported SDKs. I have an entire menu of third party documentation warnings that have nothing to do with my project so I'd love to find a way to silence these as well. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @tymac Use same solution for Pods.project

Comment: @Aznix what do you mean by "Pods.project"?

Comment: I used #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdocumentation"

Answer (score 5):

This solved it for me, surpassing the warnings **only** in the third party library headers. Just wrap the problematic header `#includes` with these `pragma`s:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdocumentation"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

this is a combination of a hint from 
[Konchog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42991455/silencing-documentation-issue-warnings-in-xcode#comment86360767_43234526) and Vladimir Grigorov’s super helpful answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52782157/1991373).