# Swift 4 - OpenCV 3.2 on Xcode 9.0 beta 2

Tags: ios, swift, opencv, swift4, xcode9-beta

I'm actualy trying to use OpenCV with ARKit to build an AR app.
For the past 6 hours I tried everything to install OpenCV on my Swift project  but that seems impossible.
I followed [this tutorial on Medium](https://medium.com/compileswift/ios-opencv-and-swift-1ee3e3a5735b) and I ended up with 3 new files with the framework : OpenCVWrapper.h and OpenCVWrapper.mm for the wrapper and LittleFarm-Bridging-Header.h for the bridging header, here is the code : 
**OpenCVWrapper.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <stdio.h>
@interface OpenCVWrapper : NSObject

- (void) isItWorking;
@end
```

**OpenCVWrapper.mm**

```
#import "OpenCVWrapper.h"
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

@implementation OpenCVWrapper

    using namespace std;
    - (void) isItWorking {
        printf("Hey");
    }
    @end
```

**LittleFarm-Bridging-Header.h**

```
#import "OpenCVWrapper.h"
```

But then I get this error : **'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found** 
I tried to figure what was the problem and I set **Framework_Search_Path to $(PROJECT_DIR).**
That doesn't change anything and if I tried to comment the related line I get this error : 
**ld: framework not found opencv2

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**
Edit : In Build Phase > Link Binary with Librairies the framework opencv2 is here.

Thanks in advance for the help !

Comment: I haven't tried it in XCode 9 yet, but that tutorial on Medium is kind of outdated. OpenCV is now available on cocoapods https://cocoapods.org/pods/OpenCV.

And I suggest you use <pod 'OpenCV', '~> 3.1.0.1'>, it's the most stable and it's working great for me. Finally, don't forget to set USE_BITCODE = false in pod target's build settings.

Comment: And in case your don't wanna use cocoapods, I think this would fix your problem: https://monosnap.com/file/EE9HHs3f214gaVuelWtU6DiKYY9L3G

Comment: I tried to install OpenCV with Cocoapods but I can't import OpenCV on my project. Some frameworks seem to be missing. Here is a screen for more informations : [link](http://i.imgur.com/8p2ephQ.png)

Comment: I tried to launch my project and I get this error : [link](https://pastebin.com/Gstubgbk)

Comment: OpenCV framework is written in C++, you simply cannot import a C++ framework to your Swift code. Instead you will need to write ObjectiveC++ wrappers (.mm files), and then import these wrappers to bridging header file, then you can use open CV with Swift.

Comment: Cocoapods doesn't do it automatically ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150603/discussion-between-alain-berrier-and-hoang-cap).

Comment: Nope. Cocoapods only copies the binary files (or source codes) to your project, then performs proper linkings/configurations to your build settings/build phases.

Comment: After doing what we discussed in chat, I still have one error : **"cuda_runtime.h" file not found cuda_stream_accessor.hpp**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finaly managed to fix my problem with the great help of [hoang Cap](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1941968/hoang-cap).

- First, instead of drag and drop the openCV framework, I install it with Cocoapods
- Notice that the version 3.2 generates some issues, 3.1.0.1 is working fine.

  *pod 'OpenCV', '~> 3.1.0.1'*
- Deactivate bitcode on both Pods target and your project.

Comment: Version rollback worked for me, from `3.3.0` to `3.1.0.1`. Saved my day

Answer (score 2):

If someone would like to use the current version or anything newer than `3.1.0.1` of OpenCV with XCode, this [workaround](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6114) helps. To ignore the documentation warnings [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27891300/690017) may also help.

Amayatsky wrote:

> I have moved `#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>` above all other imports as suggested and that did the trick.